# Why my xl2tpd doesn't redial?

Tags: debian, vpn, xl2tpd

I have a router that runs debian and is used to connect to my ISP using L2TP (over a cable modem).

xl2tpd is configured to redial if the connection fails (and pppd is configured to do a LCP ping all the time), but sometimes when the connection dies it just randomly sits there and doesn't attempt to reconnect.

Here's some excerpts from my log and config files: https://gist.github.com/bdew/b812d2608d59ee6a7d14

versions used: xl2tpd-1.3.6, pppd 2.4.6